# PayPal sandbox doesn't work

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm newbie in PayPal.
I've got the issue to integrate PayPal into mobile app. So there's in my dev account I see myLiveApp application. When I choose it and choose the sandbox I see "Something went wrong while fetching the sandbox application details. Please try again.You can still access the **Live** application details".

What does it mean? What I got to do for testing my payments in my application?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue... I hope the sandbox will turn back operative soon!

Answer (score 1):

As a test environment, sandbox is not always so stable :( Could you please try clear the browser's cookies and try again ?

Comment: I did, support answered me the same. I changed browser to chrome, then chromium, then even IE, my browser if Firefox. I tried it in Win and Linux. Sandbox doesn't work anyway. Is there another way to test payment without real transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait like me too, I have the same issue. Your best bet is to wait and see if any changes occur, that's the best answer I can give you.